# Where is this Playstation cable from?

Tags: ps3, ps-vita, psp, ps2, ps1

I have a power cable for a Playstation (unknown version), but I can't figure out what version of the console it belongs to.  Images of PS power cables that I've seen online do not look like this.

[image]

The reason I know that this is a Playstation connector is because it has a Ps Logo on the power brick.   So where is it from?

Comment: Looks like for the ps vita

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This seems to be for the ps vita.

[image]

Comment: Thank u, that's it.  Which brings up another question - where is my PS Vita!!!

Comment: Looks like looking on the sticker on that brick would have revealed it too...

Comment: It could have been after-market with little identifying marks.

Comment: @PlasmaHH There was nothing on the brick other than the Ps logo.